# How to represent similar consecutive and nonconsecutive days with 'openingHours'?

Tags: date, schema.org

If I have Su, Mo, Tu & Fr have the same time in my opening hours.

Shall I present them as (`"Su-Tu, Fr"`), (`"Su-Tu"` & `"Fr"`) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`openingHours`](https://schema.org/openingHours)’s definition, days can be separated by comma and day ranges can be specified with a hyphen.

The definition doesn’t explicitly mention that these two ways can be combined, and none of the examples use the combined way. This doesn’t necessarily mean that it’s not supported, and I would expect many consumers to support it either way, but why take chances for the little gain of saving a few characters?

You could simply list each single day, separated by comma:

```
Mo,Tu,Fr,Su
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at example 2 on openinghours. The property, like other properties, supports lists. So you can have a list item with a range and a list item with your one-off days.

> `"openingHours":["Mo-Fr 10:00-19:00", "Sa 10:00-22:00", "Su 10:00-21:00"]`
>
> taken directly from the example at https://schema.org/openingHours#tourism-2